# How to use jquery to check newly inserted elements after page is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

Ok, so I'm trying to use jquery or greasemonkey/tampermonkey userscript to create a basic chat "ding" sound whenever my username is mentioned.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $ = window.jQuery;
var jQuery = window.jQuery;

//Notify Sound preload
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = '/ding.mp3';
player.preload = 'auto';

var me = 'secretsquirrel';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
$('.chat-main').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function check(event) {
    if ($(event+'.mention:has('+me+')' === true)) {player.play(); console.log('Found my name!');}
});
}, false);
});
```

I know that DOMNodeInserted is deprecated, that's not the issue. My problem is I only want it to ding on newly inserted dom-nodes that have my username in it. The nodes are `<a>` tags with `class="mention"` nested in `<li>` attached to them and the username in a `<span>`.

If I don't user the `$(window).load(function()` the ding function works, but it does it for EVERY instance of the name, so if the page is refreshed etc it will console.log and ding multiple times.

I'm still pretty new to jquery, help? lol

Comment: Aren't you the one inserting those DOM nodes? Wouldn't it be quite trivial to just play the sound at the same time you're inserting the nodes ?

Comment: No it's an HTML5 chat being pushed from the server and added when other people chat.

Comment: [Mutation events are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Comment: But the messages aren't magically pushed to the browser, some script you or someone else wrote is receiving those messages, and appending them to the DOM, and that's where the sound should be played.

Comment: -Andreas I'm aware of that, as I mentioned in the OP. I'm open to suggestions on how else to achieve the needed result.

@adeneo: Here's a link to the site. Warning it has music live streamed so turn speakers down if not able to listen.

https://chew.tv/conquest/oxjam-chain-reaction-conquest

Comment: just set some attribute to mentions that you have ding-ed by something like `.prop('data-ding-done', '')`(for example) so that they will not ding the second time.

Answer (score 0):

IE11+

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

    // Will be something like { addedNodes: NodeList[1]}
    console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
  });
});
```

There's a [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which you can use.